# Git, Conda - How can I "pip install git+git:<repo>" with the new Git policies in place?

Tags: github, conda

I have this conda yml file for installing dependencies and creating a new conda env.

**conda_env.yml** forked from https://github.com/MishaLaskin/rad:

```
name: rad
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pytorch
  - torchvision
  - cudatoolkit=9.2
  - absl-py
  - pyparsing
  - pillow=6.1
  - pip:
    - termcolor
    - git+git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git
    - git+git://github.com/1nadequacy/dmc2gym.git
    - tb-nightly
    - imageio
    - imageio-ffmpeg
    - torchvision
    - scikit-image
    - tabulate
```

I try to run `conda env create --file conda_env.yml` and here's the stack trace I get.

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Installing pip dependencies: - Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/home/dyung6/anaconda3/envs/rad/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/home/dyung6/rad/condaenv.835gcx7g.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting git+git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git (from -r /home/dyung6/rad/condaenv.835gcx7g.requirements.txt (line 2))
  Cloning git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-nc4w5hv8

Pip subprocess error:
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git /tmp/pip-req-build-nc4w5hv8
  fatal: remote error:
    The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
  Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
WARNING: Discarding git+git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git /tmp/pip-req-build-nc4w5hv8 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git /tmp/pip-req-build-nc4w5hv8 Check the logs for full command output.
                                                                                                                                                                                                               failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Seems like the new git policies block you from doing this. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Stop using `git://` protocol. (Note: this is a GitHub issue, not a Git issue. But `https://` works fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @torek points out, and the documentation directed to in the error message explains, the `git://` protocol has phased out on GitHub. Switch to using `https://`, i.e., in this case:

```
  - pip:
    - git+https://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git
    - git+https://github.com/1nadequacy/dmc2gym.git
    ...
```